# Modifying Payload with Generated Values

Tags: spring-integration, messaging

I want to add dynamic headers to a message coming in via an http inbound endpoint. 
The goal is to return the XML payload plus the dnamically generated headers in a map as represented by
the EnhancedMessage class. The EnhancedMessage message should then be fowarded to the processChannel below;
I tried using a Header enricher as shown but I got the original message from the http inbound instead of the
message modified an returned by myBean. Can this be done? I want all the endpoints in the chain to received the headers.
The new Serializable message should look somewhat like:

```
    class EnhancedMessage implements Serializable{
    String getXMLRaw(){}
    Map<String,String> getHeaders(){}

}

    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="dataInbound"
            supported-methods="POST" status-code-``expression="T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).ACCEPTED"
            path="/ops/process" channel="processChannel">
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:chain input-channel="processChannel">
         <int:header-enricher>
             <ref bean="myBean"/>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:recipient-list-router>
            <int:recipient channel="out1" />
            <int:recipient channel="out2" />
        </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>

Everything works except the message enhancement. I would appreciate any directions on how to proceed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Header Enricher is exactly for `headers` it does nothing with `payload`.

From one side you can consider to just `<enricher>`, who can modify the part of `payload`.

Or even full `<transformer>` which allow you to have a full control over message - its `headers` and `payload`.

Please, read more [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

Comment: Thank you Artem, very much appreciated!